# save_post hook wordpress not updating metadata

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to call a python script when I press update on a wordpress post. This works well but I am noticing that if I just update the metadata of the post, this is not updated. How can I fix it? Is there a method that I can call to save the metadata post as well?

This is my code:

```
  function mysave($id, $post) 
{

    if ($post->post_type != 'item'){
        return;
    }

     if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( (defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) ){    
     return; 
    }

   


    if (wp_is_post_revision($id)) {
        return;
    }

    if (wp_is_post_autosave($id)) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ( 'trash' === $post->post_status ) {
        return;
    }

     if ( 'draft' === $post->post_status ) {
        return;
    }



    $dig = get_post_meta($id, 'wpcf-digitisation-project-no')[0];
    #$hmml = get_post_meta($id, 'wpcf-hmml-project-no')[0];
    $inv = get_post_meta($id, 'wpcf-inventory-no')[0];
    
    if($dig!=""){
        $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 '. dirname(__file__). '/create_pdf.py digital '.$inv);
    }else{
        $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 '. dirname(__file__). '/create_pdf.py hmml '.$inv);
     }
    
    exec( $command, $output, $ret_code);

    if($ret_code != 0){
        $tmp = fopen(dirname(__file__).'/my_logs.txt', "a+"); 
        fwrite($tmp,"\nFailed to create pdf for record with inventory number: ".get_post_meta($id, 'wpcf-inventory-no')[0]."\n");
        fclose($tmp); 
    }else{
        $tmp = fopen(dirname(__file__).'/my_logs.txt', "a+"); 
        fwrite($tmp,"\nPDF successfully created for record with inventory number: ".get_post_meta($id, 'wpcf-inventory-no')[0]."\n");
        fclose($tmp); 
    }

    
    

}
```

Comment: You can use update_post_meta() to update the post metadata.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/